# How to use Facebook Graph API to read Instagram user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I tried to use Graph API Explorer to read an Instagram user.

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-user/

I ticked every permission to generate the access token. Also, I linked my Instagram account to Facebook account. However, response still showed as 'Unsupported get request'.

[graph api explorer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEhXi.png)

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has just released a new version of their graph API (v2.10) that now contains a new [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/instagram-api/v2.10) that has new permissions that should allow you to read an Instagram user.

- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_comments (optional)
- instagram_manage_insights (optional)

However, these permissions are currently limited to Instagram business users that also have a Facebook business account with an ad account linked to it.

Comment: so we need an ad account in order to use the API? We must pay to use?

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation does describe this feature, my guess is that they removed it when they [revised the Instagram API and significantly limited the functionality](https://www.dialogfeed.com/update-instagram-api-changes-restrictions-solutions/) back in June of 2016.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to get the username of user who post the comment you can get it when you retrieve comment via media api
*see 'note' section in here : [instagram user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user#metadata)